# How to avoid juice flowing out of meatloaf when puncturing it with a thermometer?

Tags: meatloaf

When baking meatloaf an related dishes, I've noticed that sometimes a large amount of liquid will flow out after I puncture the meatloaf with a thermometer. I imagine it would be better if the juice stayed in while letting the meatloaf cool down, to give a more moist meatloaf. What would you suggest to avoid this issue, while still being safe?

Note: I do sometimes supplement bread crumbs with coconut flour to reduce the carbs in the meatloaf, rather than just using bread crumbs, so this might partially be responsible. I also tend to use 2:1 ratio of ground poultry to beef.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the ability to do so, cook the meatloaf with a probe or thermometer in it. That is certainly the approach I take when I have to cook a pork or poultry meatloaf or something of the like.

Otherwise, I would recommend a high angle of attack (think 30-45 degrees) from outer corner towards center of mass and you may get away with some plain-ole physics of the juices not having an efficient exit.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Egg.**

I don't like runny meatloaf either & my meatloaf usually has onion in it which gives off juice.  Many meatloaf recipes call for an egg.  I think the egg sets up inside the meatloaf and traps juice.  If you are not adding an egg try it.  No carbs in egg!

Also instead of coconut flour you could use dry instant mashed potatoes.  It is thirsty stuff.  It is super subtle in the finished product.  It is not low carb though.